# Cannot get an array in Angular

Tags: angular

I've used ASP.NET Core API. The API works fine. When I try to get data from API, it shows the following error in the browser:

[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBWI6.png)

**header.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { faAppleWhole } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faRightToBracket } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { Topic } from '../Models/topic.model';
import { TopicService } from '../Services/topic.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  faAppleWhole = faAppleWhole;
  faRightToBracket = faRightToBracket

  //Defining topics (to use in the page as an array)
  topics: Topic[] = [];

  constructor(private topicService:TopicService) 
  { 

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.GetAllTopics();
  }


  GetAllTopics(){
    this.topicService.GetAllTopics().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.topics = response
        console.log(this.topics);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**topic.service.ts:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Topic } from '../Models/topic.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TopicService {

  baseURL = "https://localhost:5001/api/topics";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
  { 

  }

  GetAllTopics(): Observable<Topic[]>{
    return this.http.get<Topic[]>(this.baseURL + "/getalltopics");
  }

}
```

**header.component.html:**

```
<div class="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2">
        <nav class="nav d-flex justify-content-start" *ngFor="let topic of topics">
            <a class="p-2 link-secondary" href="#">{{ topic.Name }}</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

I have used an array for `topics` but the output is not an array. What is the problem?

Comment: Your response is an object which has a result array. You can only itterate over arrays so either use topics.result or assign this.topics to   response.result

Comment: @MikeOne Can you please write your response in code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line `this.topics = response` to `this.topics = response.result`

Comment: It says: result does not exist on type Topic[]. It fails to compile.

Comment: You answer did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by making some changes in the structure of API output.
I had used the `ToListAsync()` method in the action (ASP.NET Core API) without using `await`. I added `await` and the output turned into array.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).